# Varnish keeps crashing on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, magento2, centos6, varnish-4

I have installed Magneto 2 on EC2 with a MySQL database hosted separately on a RDS instance. I have configured the varnish on my EC2 server.

Whenever I open multiple tabs on the website, the varnish server crashes on a couple of product pages with the following error:

> Error 503 Backend fetch failed"

Varnish version: 4.0.4 on Centos 6

Comment: Are you sure varnish is crashing?  That isn't what this error sounds like.  How do you recover from this error?

Comment: when I hit refresh it throws the same error and then I wait for a couple of seconds then i try to reload the page it loads, and sometimes i have to restart the varnish server. The problem occurs on some pages and rest of the pages load just fine.

Comment: Read the logs for [varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/tips/varnishlog/fetcherror.html) and for your web server.  And maybe [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/tshoot-varnish-503.html).  There is nothing about this error that sounds like varnish is "crashing," or that varnish is even having a problem.  It sounds like varnish is *reporting* the problem, and that's a very different circumstance than crashing.

Comment: I already tried the solution given in the link to the magento guide for 503 backend error, didn't seem to work though. Thanks for the link. I''l post back when I figure it out.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, there are these 5 subcategories (all configurable ones) that are throwing the error. Rest of the pages are loading alright.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally figured out what the reason was. We had the website silently running for testing without problems for a week. When we pointed our domain to the amazon EC2 instance - varnish crashed after some hours.

But that was maybe a coincidence. I found out someone was scraping the ip to find some access. logs were full of access tries to /sql /phpmyadmin /administrator ...and so on. 
That caused varnish crashing.